# Problem with reindexing process SQLSTATE[23000]?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, database, sql

I've a problem with re-indexing data in magento. When I click reindex data , It returns this error :

```
There was a problem with reindexing process. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_shop`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `catalog_category_product_index_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASC)
```

So I've searched around for a solution for hours and days ...
But I couldn't find a way to fix it.
I think there's a value in database in product_id which is not in entity_id , That's the cause. 
So I went into phpmyadmin and ran these queries :

```
# Determine incorrect product associations
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE
product_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);

# Determine incorrect categories
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE 
category_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_category_entity);
```

To find and delete records which is not in both tables, But these queries returns 0 results ! 
So how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Database Repair** tool.

This will

```
- Adds missing tables, or repairs them so they have the same engine type and charset
- Adds missing fields or repairs them
- Removes inconsistent data from tables with broken foreign key references
- Adds missing foreign keys and indexes
```

Check here for more : http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html

Comment: Are you sure this is the right way to fix this issue ? I think this happens just for a missing record not having problems with whole database.

Comment: @MostafaSafarian: does this helps ?